# Determine competence of classes before further working with them

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote a shell extension which sorts files in folder. The structure I have is that for all types of files have their own classes, where I have custom internal methods to sort.

In all classes are lists with string types of extensions. The problem is I don't know how to define the type file for first step to create appropriate object and continue sorting. (EDIT: i.e. which class should sort which file type.)

The first this is primary sorting, we get all files in a directory and then we take one file and check it, if it belongs to one of the existing file types, then we should use the sort method which belong to appropriate class.
The moment I cant fix is "check it, if it belongs to one of the existing file types".

File types are presented as an separate classes. So, for jpeg or png, I have class Graphics, this class contains the secondary sorting, but first of all we need to know that the file belongs to Graphics.

Now I made this kind of sorting like this, just creating objects in start and then check

```
public void PrimarySorting(string folderPath)
    {

        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
        while (allFiles.Count != 0)
        {
            allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
                foreach (var file in allFiles)
                {
                    var directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath).Name;
                    var fileType = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    var sourcePath = file;
                    //var destinationPath = folderPath + "/" + area + directoryName + "/" + fileName;
                    char[] toRemoveFromExtensionString = {'.', '"'};
                    if (fileType != null)
                    {
                        var extensionLikeSymbols = fileType.Trim(toRemoveFromExtensionString).ToLower();
                        var gr = new Graphics();
                        var arc = new Archive();

                        if (
                            gr.ColorManagement.Union(gr.ColorPalettes)
                                .Union(gr.RasterGraphics)
                                .Union(gr.VectorGraphics)
                                .Union(gr.ThreeDimensionalGraphics)
                                .Contains(extensionLikeSymbols))
                        {
                            var objectToCallMethod = new Graphics();
                            objectToCallMethod.CustomSortForParticularArea(extensionLikeSymbols, file,
                                folderPath, objectToCallMethod, sourcePath, directoryName);
                        }

                        else if (
                            arc.Compressed.Union(arc.PhysicalRecordableMediaArchives)
                                .Contains(extensionLikeSymbols))
                        {
                            var objectToCallMethod = new Archive();
                            ;
                            objectToCallMethod.CustomSortForParticularArea(extensionLikeSymbols, file,
                                folderPath, objectToCallMethod, sourcePath, directoryName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Please replace the image of code with text.

Comment: An actual ShellExtension in NET code is ill-advised: [Guidance for Implementing In-Process Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx) namely: **Microsoft recommends against writing managed in-process extensions to Windows Explorer or Windows Internet Explorer and does not consider them a supported scenario.**

Comment: @Plutonix I write if only for myself to learn code more deeply, so it's me to me, not business to business.

Comment: @miroxlav I fixed code. It difficult to explain more clearly. I can tell more if you will  ask any concrete question..

Comment: File type registrations are something the user or software sets up.  I am having a hard time understanding why a sorter would ever create file types.

Comment: @Plutonix No, maybe you don't understand what I exactly do. For example, my folder Downloads on Mac looks awfully, a lot of files,  I cant find sometimes anything, so this extension will clean up the mess. It will sort files by extension and put these files in the folders with normal names, will make some kind of group by.

Comment: You say *The problem is I don't know how to define the type file for first step*. Whay exactly do you mean by *type file*? I do not undestand that term.

Comment: @miroxlav I mean type as type of class, when I get file I want to know which class I should use, graphics, archives, so I don't know how to find out it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to come up with a good answer because I haven't seen the source code of `Graphics` and `Archive`, but I'll try anyway.

As I understand both `Graphics` and `Archive` have `CustomSortForParticularArea` method which does all the magic. It searches for files with specified extension(s) and moves them to appropriate folder(s). (I'm not sure whether you need to have a dedicated class for each "extension group" for the sake of copying files. I assume `Graphics` and `Archive` do something else apart from just copying files.)

What I've also understood is that you need to create two objects instead of one. For example, if it was a "png" file then the app would have created `Graphics` and `Archive` objects. Obviously it's not the way to go, because you want to use an object of appropriate class. There are multiple solutions to your problem. I'll explain just one of them when `Graphics` and `Archive` are not aware of file extensions and object initiation is delegated to another class, for example, to a factory.

This is a base class for your "sorters" classes. It may implement the logic which can be reused in subclasses and/or it may define a protocol for subclasses to implement. It might be a regular class, a class with virtual methods which would be overridden, an abstract class or you could use an interface instead of a class. It's up to you to decide. The main idea is to have an abstraction that represents `Graphics` and `Archive` or to have a protocol which must be implemented by `Graphics` and `Archive`. I will use a normal class for the sake of simplicity.

```
public class BespokeFileSorter
{
    public void CustomSortForParticularArea(string extensionLikeSymbols, string file, string folderPath, string sourcePath, string directoryName)
    {
        // finds file(s) with expention(s) in folder(s) and copies them to filder(s)
    }
    // other methods
}
```

`Graphics` and `Archive` already know how to find and copy files because they subclass (or inherit) `BespokeFileSorter`.

```
public class Graphics : BespokeFileSorter
{
    // other methods
}

public class Archive : BespokeFileSorter
{
    // other methods
}
```

This is a factory which is responsible for creation of "sorters". It's the only class which knows what object to create according to provided information. You need to choose the minimum required data which factory would use to decide what object to create. I assume a file extension would be enough. So, if you pass "png" it will create an object of type `Graphics`. If you pass "iso" it will create an object of type `Archive`. Anyway it will return `BespokeFileSorter`. If you're having troubles understanding how it works I'd recommend you to read about OOP.

```
public static class BespokeFileSorterFactory
{
    private static HashSet<string> supportedGraphicExtensions = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "jpeg", "png" // Raster, vector, 3D, etc. graphics
    };
    private static HashSet<string> supportedArchiveExtensions = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "ison", "nrg" // and others
    };

    public static BespokeFileSorter Create(string fileExtension)
    {
        if (supportedGraphicExtensions.Contains(fileExtension))
            return new Graphics();

        if (supportedArchiveExtensions.Contains(fileExtension))
            return new Archive();

        throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown file extension");
    }
}
```

Finally, somewhere in your code you can do something like that. Pass file extension to the factory and let it decide which object to create. Call required method of newly created object to find and copy files.

```
var bespokeFileSorter = BespokeFileSorterFactory.Create(extensionLikeSymbols);
bespokeFileSorter.CustomSortForParticularArea(extensionLikeSymbols, file, folderPath, sourcePath, directoryName);
```

There are other improvements which can be made to your code. You could have a cache for class(-es) (`Graphics` and `Archive` are being created in every iteration). You could also refactor *unions* and *contains* which I believe complicates your domain model. And the most important thing to remember is that you should keep your classes small and make them responsible for a few things only. If you need a class for copying files then make a class which does it and don't add additional responsibilities to it. /probably a bad example because .NET got it/ Tip: Google for SOLID principles.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly that explanation which I wanted to hear! Everything is clear, I rebuilt my code with your advices and everything work fine.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite sure whether I got your question right, but I try to answer.

I see that in your source code you demonstrate classes Graphics and Archive for purposes of handling image and archive files.

You can give your classes common ancestor like FileTypeBase which will contain virtual (static) method `SupportedExtensions()` returning array (or list) of supported extensions. Then inherit your classes Graphics and Archive from this class. In Graphics class, implement the method so it will return list containing "jpeg","png". The same method from Archive class will return `"zip","rar"` etc., you get the idea.

Then in your main method you can call this method on already known classes and this way determine which class server which extensions (and whether you already have it instantiated or not etc).

Comment: It looks like something which is very close to solution, but can you explain a calling of the method SupportedExtensions() in the main class, I don't understand how exactly should I use it for choosing classes? Thanks for trying to solve this.

Comment: @whoiskatrin – are you familiar with class inheritance in C#?

Comment: yes, I do, I know how to do it, I don't understand how exactly will work the method from the main

Comment: i don't understand abstract part, technical is okey ;)

Comment: "Then in your main method you can call this method on already known classes and this way determine which class server which extensions (and whether you already have it instantiated or not etc)."

This moment one more time, please..